General approach to solving math problems
I have a mathematical function f(x,y) -> z. I want a ml model to learn to approximate f for any x,y. I tried a transformer approach, where the input files are just a bunch of equations, but it doesn’t seem to work/generalize that well. Is there any good approach or model that is tailored to solving complex math equations?

Please add more rigor and detail to your question. Also, did you mean “complex” which has a particular meaning in mathematics? Or “complicated” which is more of a layperson’s word?

The latter, I already thought this might not be the right place to ask such unspecific question.

This seems to be asking how to do predictive modeling, which is far too broad for Cross Validated. That is answered by a textbook (maybe a whole library), not a post on here. Is there a more specific question?
